# Copy file from linux to remote windows machine using staf

Tags: linux, windows, staf

Assumming the following error is because the same path on local system does not exist on the remote system.
Is there a way to specify an alternative path to save on remote system?

```
[root@linuxsystem mydir]# staf local FS COPY FILE /root/scripts/tests/script.bat TOMACHINE remoteVM
Error submitting request, RC: 17
Additional info
---------------
\root\scripts\tests\script.bat
```

Error information:

```
17  File Open Error
This indicates that there was an error opening the requested file.
Some possible explanations are that the file/path does not exist, contains invalid characters, or is locked.

Note: Additional information regarding which file could not be opened may be provided in the result passed back from the submit call.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found correct command:

```
staf local FS COPY FILE /root/scripts/tests/script.bat TODIRECTORY "C:\" TOMACHINE remoteVM
```